# What is the best approach for extracting, transforming, and loading data from MongoDB to PostgreSQL using Node.js streams and pipes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, etl

How to create a data pipeline from mongoDB to postgreSQL?
MongoDB contains data from third party services and is used as an intermediary database while, postgreSQL will be used as the main database that runs the application.

What would be the high level approach to tackle this situation? Tech used is nodejs , bullMQ for background process.

I am confused regarding how to go about using nodejs streams and pipes to extract transform and load data from mongoDB to postgreSQL. The ETL process shall be done in the background using bullMQ.